# How can I install CUDA on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, cuda

For TensorFlow I would like to install CUDA. How do I do that on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: For CUDA toolkit 9.1 on Ubuntu 16.04, this hindsight post may be helpful: http://tech.amikelive.com/node-669/guide-installing-cuda-toolkit-9-1-on-ubuntu-16-04/ Similar with @Atlas7 post, the installation process also relies on the deb (network) method instead of using runfile (local) as seen in the accepted answer.

Comment: WARNING: don't use the "run-script", like in the accepted answer. You'll F* your system when you apt-get-upgrade your kernel.

Comment: I have written a github readme.md file explaining every step in sufficient detail. You can have a look at it: https://github.com/bhavykhatri/Installing-_CUDA_toolkit_guide_LINUX/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 100, accepted):

### Install CUDA for Ubuntu

There is an [Linux installation guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7.5/Prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf). However, it is basically only these steps:

1. [Download CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads): I used the 15.04 version and "runfile (local)". That is 1.1 GB.
2. Check the md5 sum: `md5sum cuda_7.5.18_linux.run`. Only continue if it is correct.
3. Remove any other installation (`sudo apt-get purge nvidia-cuda*` - if you want to install the drivers too, then `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`.)

   - If you want to install the display drivers<sup>(*)</sup>, logout from your GUI. Go to a terminal session (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>)
   - Stop lightdm: `sudo service lightdm stop`
4. Create a file at `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf` with the following contents:

   ```
   blacklist nouveau
   options nouveau modeset=0
   ```
5. Then do: `sudo update-initramfs -u`
6. `sudo sh cuda_7.5.18_linux.run --override`. Make sure that you say `y` for the symbolic link.
7. Start lightdm again: `sudo service lightdm start`
8. Follow the command-line prompts

See also: [NVIDIA CUDA with Ubuntu 16.04 beta on a laptop (if you just cannot wait)](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/NVIDIA-CUDA-with-Ubuntu-16-04-beta-on-a-laptop-if-you-just-cannot-wait-775/)

**Notes**: Yes, there is the possibility to install it via `apt-get install cuda`. I strongly suggest not to use it, as it changes the paths and makes the installation of other tools more difficult.

You might also be interested in [How can I install CuDNN on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/767269/10425).

*: Don't install the display drivers with this script. They are old. Download the latest ones from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

### Verify CUDA installation

The following command shows the current CUDA version (last line):

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Sep__4_22:14:01_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.44
```

The following command shows your driver version and how much GPU memory you have:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Fri Jan 20 12:19:04 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.57                 Driver Version: 367.57                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 940MX       Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   75C    P0    N/A /  N/A |   1981MiB /  2002MiB |     98%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1156    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             246MiB |
|    0      3198    G   ...m,SecurityWarningIconUpdate<SecurityWarni   222MiB |
|    0      6645    C   python                                        1510MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

See also: [Verify CuDNN installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36978616/562769)

### Help! The new driver does not work!

Don't panic. Even if you can't see anything on your computer, the following steps should get you back to the state before:

1. Press <kbd>shift</kbd> during startup
2. Go into a root shell
3. Make it writable by running `mount -o remount,rw /` (`-` is `?` and `/` is `-` in the american layout)
4. `sh cuda_7.5.18_linux.run --uninstall`
5. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-common nvidia-prime nvidia-settings`

### Graphics drivers

Installing the graphics drivers is a bit tricky. This has to be done without graphics support.

1. Log out from your current X session.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (you can switch back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>)
3. You should remove all other drivers before.

- Search for them via `dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia`
- Remove them via `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-WHATEVER`

4. Stop lightdm via `sudo service lightdm stop`
5. You might need to `reboot` your pc / blacklist the nouveau driver ([German tutorial](http://linuxwelt.blogspot.de/2014/08/losung-error-nouveau-kernel-driver-is.html))

Comment: thank you, great! is there a way to skip the liscense term straight to the end?

Comment: @Boern I'm sorry, I don't know. You could have a look at the Docker image for Tensorflow with GPU to check how they do it there.

Comment: @Boern I think you can just press 'q' to skip it

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me whether to first follow the procedure at the third point, or to follow the instructions under Graphic drivers when I want to reinstall the graphic drivers

Comment: You need to say no to the opengl drivers.  You can also pass the flag --no-opengl-lib to the .run install file https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/installing-nvidia-cuda-80-ubuntu-1604-linux-gpu-new-victor/

Comment: Thanks for this; I am trying but keep getting ```$ sudo sh cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux.run --override
sh: 0: Can't open cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux.run
```

Comment: and always remember to run `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) ` before running the installer. this makes sure kernel headers and development packages specific to what you are running is there and you wont be facing failed driver installations!

Comment: In order to get things working, I had to add the lines
`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin` and 
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64`
to mi .bashrc file. Without this, the command `nvcc` was not recognized. Note that the specific folder would change according to the CUDA version and your system architecture.

Answer (score 23):

I tried to install many times via the .run file, but some error always crept in and I either ran into a login loop or completely lost the display. Therefore I would recommend to use the .deb file and not fiddle with the display manager.

[NVIDIA CUDA Installation Guide for Linux](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#axzz4WNL7OgLr)
is an excellent link that lists the complete details.Make sure you follow each step as it is given .

To install the Nvidia driver you can do the following:

1. In Ubuntu **Search your Computer** menu at the left top corner search **Additional Drivers** (You might also do **System Settings > Software and Updates > Additional Drivers**)
2. In the menu that appears select one of the Nvidia Drivers and click **Apply Changes**. (This step uses the internet. If it still fails then your proxy server might be blocking the download)
3. Reboot your system.
4. Open a terminal window and type `nvidia-smi`. If your driver has been installed correctly you should see something like:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 3.295.41   Driver Version: 295.41         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| Nb.  Name                     | Bus Id        Disp.  | Volatile ECC SB / DB |
| Fan   Temp   Power Usage /Cap | Memory Usage         | GPU Util. Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
| 0.  Tesla C2050               | 0000:05:00.0  On     |         0          0 |
|  30%   62 C  P0    N/A /  N/A |   3%   70MB / 2687MB |   44%     Default    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------|
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU  PID     Process name                                       Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  0.  7336     ./align                                                 61MB  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can easily install CUDA according to the previous link now. In brief:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Download a toolkit [from here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) and then install the `.deb` file (replace name accordingly)

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-<distro>_<version>_<architecture>.deb
```

then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

Comment: I just installed this on a brand spanking new Linux Mint KDE setup (2017-05-24) with GeForce 1080 TI, and it worked. Choose the "deb (network)"-variant on the web page, as both just installs an apt-source in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/, but the "deb (local)" is a local file pointer, while the other ("network") is a normal link to a repo. It reads as such, and you can probably just enter itself, the file is called "cuda.list": `deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubun‌​‌​tu1604/x86_64 /`. Note that the install downgraded the driver from nvidia-381 to -375. I left it there.

Comment: @akshita007   When I go to additional drivers I see this message:  `Unknown: Unknown This device is not working`   It then asks me if I want to use `Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs`. Should I be using that? Thank you.

Comment: To everyone else reading @stolsvik's comment, there is a white space near the end.

Comment: This won't work. Besides the pre-steps, `sudo apt-get install cuda` will install the latest version (10.2 by now)

Answer (score 7):

I also tried difference approaches so as to install Cuda 8.0 in Ubuntu 16.04. Finally, these are the steps which do the trick. I followed [this tutorial](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?21956-(Guide)-Installing-Nvidia-Bumblebee-CUDA-for-Optimus-enabled-Laptops) and updated corrected steps as follows.

1. Update the system

   ```
   apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
   ```
2. Download [VirtualGL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualgl/files/) and install it. To install

   ```
   dpkg -i virtualgl*.deb
   ```
3. Download and install [CUDA 8.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)　and install it. I suggest to do it vs through the internet. As like this,

   [image]
4. Install required dependencies.

   ```
   apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
   apt-get install freeglut3-dev libxmu-dev libpcap-dev
   ```
5. Update system PATH in .bashrc which can be found in the home directory. Please note if you install those thing into difference location, please update path according to that.

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/opt/VirtualGL/bin
   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin
   ```
6. Install bumblebee-nvidia and primus.

   ```
   apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia primus
   ```
7. Edit the bumblebee config file so bumblebee knows we are using the NVIDIA driver. Please update the path according to your system. Here is reference view which will help.

   ```
   sudo nano +22 /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
   ```

   Add:

   ```
   [bumblebeed]
   ServerGroup=bumblebee
   TurnCardOffAtExit=false
   NoEcoModeOverride=false
   Driver=nvidia
   XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d
   Bridge=auto
   PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
   AllowFallbackToIGC=false
   Driver=nvidia
   [driver-nvidia]
   KernelDriver=nvidia
   PMMethod=auto
   LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-367:/usr/lib32/nvidia-367
   XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
   XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
   Driver=nouveau
   [driver-nouveau]
   KernelDriver=nouveau
   PMMethod=auto
   XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
   ```
8. Run the following and record the PCI address of your video card.

   ```
   $ lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'
   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
   01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 179c (rev a2)
   ```
9. Edit the xorg.conf.nvidia file so it knows the PCI address(01:00.0 for me) of your video card. Update PIC address as below under section "ServerLayout"

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
   ```

   Add:

   ```
   Section "ServerLayout"
       Identifier  "Layout0"
       Option      "AutoAddDevices" "false"
       Option      "AutoAddGPU" "false"
       BusID "PCI:01:00.0"
   ```
10. Reboot the system and have a fun with running some sample codes.

    ```
    sudo shutdown -r now
    ```

Answer (score 4):

This is a looooong answer as i was screwing my laptop several times while writing it. However, I rather to keep it long since it maybe useful for other people too ;)
The best part of my answer starts from **Edited-Updated**

Sooooo, I read all the answers here and other places, I dont know why, but each of them cause me an issue :(

After 4 days, re installing Linux back and forth here is the way that worked for me.

Before going to the main procedure i want to mention an alternative method.

**alternative method if you are using a laptop:**

So you can switch between your nvidia and your intel gpu on your laptop by using

```
sudo prime-select intel
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

In other words, you can switch to intel and install nvidia and the switch back to intel for normal usages and whenever you want to use deep learning switch to nvidia one.

**Anyway,**

let me talk about the main method that finally works for me (info here are mainly grabbed from [Link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile-nouveau)):

**Deleting and purging all existing nvidia/cuda stuff:**

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-cuda*
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall
sudo /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/uninstall_cuda_8.0.pl
sudo rm -rf  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
```

Then, we just update everything:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Now, there would be a possibility that you cannot log in and you get stuck in the loop...

No worries, I faced that more than 50 times...

press `ctr+alt+F2`
type your username and password

now type these:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Optional, some people also need to type this, honestly idk what is the use of it: `sudo init 3`

```
sudo nano  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
```

add

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

to it and save it and exit.

Then type:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

go to the file that you have cuda .run file there and type:

```
sudo sh cuda_8.0_linux.run --override
sudo service lightdm start
sudo reboot
```

Sooo, if you are lucky, you should be able to login now. As you may guess, i was not a lucky one, and I still could not f**** login.
So i had to press `ctr+Alt+F2` again and do the following:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo reboot
```

Now i could login finally.

Now it is the time to set the paths and check the installations.

type:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64                         ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}

nvidia-smi
nvcc -V
```

it should show you that you have cuda 8.

Also just in case you can also do these:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64


gedit ~/.bashrc
```

add these at the end:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64

# Added by me on 2013/06/24
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Save and exit gedit.
Type:

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
```

**A question for the people who knows more than me:**

So everything sounds like working but when I shutdown/reboot my system for a few seconds it shows

So everything sounds like working but when I shutdown/reboot my system for a few seconds it shows **“Failed to start Load Kernel Modules”** I tryied this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779251/what-to-do-after-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules) but it is not helping, please let me know if you know how to fix it.

**----------------**

**Edited-Updated**

Guess what, I screwed again.

But this time I came with a much easier solusion. and here is the main point: **Sometimes we need to say NO**

Here is what works really good for me. after you purge and remove everything and sudo reboot do this:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo reboot
```

press `ctr+alt+F2`
type your username and password

now type these:

```
sudo service lightdm stop

sudo sh cuda_8.0_linux.run
```

**IMPORTANT:** during the installation, the first question asks for reinstalling the driver again, **SAY NO to this mother f**** question**
Say yes to the rest of them though  :D
after finishing.

```
sudo service lightdm start
press `alt+ctr+F7`
```

login to your dear PC

Did it work? Your Welcome :)

Comment: Man,your answer is invaluable as in my case I must hardcode the path into the file as you explained on pretty every machine I use. Very important info. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelIV Not so. This answer has a lot of mistakes, redundant commands and in general shows a lack of understanding. This reads as a mix-match of things that the use probably read somewhere but didn't understand correctly. And that the user tried to be funny (childish) doesn't help either. Any other answer here is better and way more practical.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work after reading several posts:
I had an ATI card in the computer already which turned out to be very useful. I installed GTX 1070 along side of the ATI and started installing Kubuntu 16.04. Only the display connected to the ATI card had image initially, which allowed me to install the driver NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.27.run  downloaded from the vendor's website. To install CUDA, I downloaded the cuda_7.5.18_linux.run file. I installed the cuda toolkit by using two switches:

`cuda_7.5.18_linux.run --silent --toolkit`

The cuda samples can also be installed from the .run file. One issue was cuda does not like gcc5. So I did `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8` and then changed the default gcc to this version by:

```
cd /usr/bin/
sudo unlink gcc
sudo ln -s gcc4.8 gcc
sudo unlink g++
sudo ln -s g++-4.8 g++
```

I replaced gcc to gcc5 after cuda is installed. Compiling the cuda samples also need to be done with gcc4.8, gcc4.9 might work but I did not try it.

Comment: The CUDA installer respects the CC environment variable, so you can set that to point to gcc-4.8, rather than needing to mess around with your system-wide symlinks.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog post on this a while ago - [Nvidia CUDA toolkit installation - ubuntu 16.04 LTS - notes/](http://mathalope.co.uk/2017/05/31/nvidia-cuda-toolkit-installation-ubuntu-16-04-lts-notes/)

My environment: Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

---

Posting some major learnings here. Please see the blog post for detailed instructions (just to avoid duplication)

- Disable Secure Boot at UEFI Firmware setting (do this in BIOS mode / restart from Windows advanced startup). (I did try for ages hoping I could get it working with Secure Boot enabled. No luck *Secure Boot stopped the Nvidia driver from installing properly on Ubuntu*. Disabling Secure Boot turns out to be the only working solution for me - if you are able to get Nvidia driver installed without having to disable Secure Boot, do let me know)
- Follow the [Linux CUDA Installation Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/).
- (my opinion) Use the Linux .deb (package manager) installation (for simplicity.). Download the .deb file in a browser. Install from terminal command line.
- (my opinion) Don't use runfile installation (too complicated).

Answer (score 2):

The steps that worked for me:

1. sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit **OR** 1'. the installation instructions [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html)
2. You need to select from Software&Updates/Additional Drivers the nvidia driver (375, in my context)
3. Follow the blue screen when you **restart** and only from there disable secure boot by inputting your password set during nvidia driver install. (any secure boot disabling through the BIOS did not work for me).

Now the installation test output is successful.

Answer (score 1):

A generally preferred method is to install SW is via deb files when available as they provide a more robust way to handle dependencies and a more reliable method for removing SW. The CUDA 8.0 release-candidate was available for 16.04 (in the dev zone) that way and now the CUDA 8.0 for Ubuntu 16.04 is available via deb files (local) and (network) :https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Comment: I've used this method for a while, but after putting a 1080 card in, which doesn't drive the display, and CUDA 8, my Ubuntu desktop is gone. Here we go again...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
sudo rm /tmp/.X*-lock
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo reboot
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd>

```
sudo rmmod nvidia
sudo sh cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux.run 
sudo service lightdm start
```

and reboot

Answer (score 1):

Just a kind reminder, Ubuntu 16.04 might not install cuda at the assumed location `/usr/local/cuda-8.0.61`. Hence `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0.61/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}` may not work.

When I was trying to install "cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb" on Ubuntu 16.04, I simply followed the instructions here http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions. However, I was not able to compile 
cuda-install-samples-8.0.61.sh \home
or nvcc -V

It turned out that Ubuntu installed cuda in `/usr/local/cuda-8.0` instead of the assumed location `/usr/local/cuda-8.0.61`. Hence I changed `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0.61/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}` into `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}` and I successfully installed cuda.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for my case. I was installing CUDA 8.0 on my labtop with following specifications:

- Graphics Card: GeForce GTX 950M (cc 5.0)
- CPU: Intel Core i7-6700HQ (with Intel HD Graphics 530)

The following guide installs the NVIDIA driver first, and then installs CUDA 8.0.

---

#### Installing CUDA 8.0 on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04

1. Launch [Software & Updates]. Select [Additional Drivers] tab.
2. In the list, find your graphic card. Among the drivers that can be used for the card, choose the proprietary driver from NVIDIA. Then press [Apply Changes] button. In my case, under the graphics card name "NVIDIA Corporation: GM107M [Geforce GTX 950M]", there were two selections:

   - Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 375.66 from nvidia-375 (proprietary, tested)
   - Using X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)
3. Delete default installed video drivers with `$ sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-video*`.
4. Reboot.
5. Download CUDA 8.0 Toolkit from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). Among the installer types, choose "runfile (local)". This downloads `cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux.run`.
6. Run the installer with `$ sudo sh cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux.run`.

   - [Optional] If your currently installed NVIDIA driver version is higher than the driver version contained in the downloaded installer, you can choose not to install the driver while installing CUDA. In my case, since I already have driver version `375.66`, which is higher than `375.26` contained in the installer, I chose not to install.
7. After install, config your binary path and library path (You can follow the directions from the instller). If you choose to configure `ld.so.conf` and the following error occurs: `libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link`, follow the direction from [this link](https://askubuntu.com/q/900285/663208).

Answer (score 1):

I initially tried doing that `sudo lightdm stop` stuff, but it lead to a login loop. So I found a new method:

1. Copy the file `cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run` (in my case it was runfile) to any directory in `/home/<your_username>` like Downloads or Documents or anywhere.
2. After that restart your computer and when Ubuntu boot menu appears go to 'Advanced Options → Recovery Mode' (if it does not appear hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> key while booting)
3. Select 'drop to root shell', press ENTER to proceed when asked for pressing enter or Ctrl-D.

   **Edit**: Run `mount -o rw,remount /` to get read-write priviliges.
4. Go into that directory where you have copied the cuda installation file.
5. Run the command on the basis of type of file, it can be found at https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads after selecting your desired target as you have done earlier. In my case it was `sudo sh cuda_*.run`
6. This is **important step** and **proceed slowly and carefully**, when the long information/agreement ends **ACCEPT** it.
7. Then it will ask about the **NVIDIA DRIVER INSTALLATION** press **yes**(**y**).
8. Then it will probably ask about **OpenGL libraries installation**, **skip it because it may override your normal driver installation and cause problems**, in my case it did. So Press **no**(**n**).
9. Then go ahead with all the installations and it will complete automatically and at last show the **logfile in `/tmp`**.
10. Now **reboot the system** by entering the reboot command at the recovery mode shell.
11. After your system starts it might not show the CUDA sample files, because you need to complete these two mandatory post-installation steps :

    > [A] Add the correct path for cuda.
    >
    > [B] Add correct path for LD_LIBRARY_PATH

    Add the path to ~/.bashrc file and run `source ~/.bashrc` to make the path permanent so that it didn't vanish after reboot, confirm it by closing the current terminal and running the second command in step 12 again in another terminal.

    Refer to [Go to 7. Post-Installation Actions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html)
12. To check whether CUDA is installed properly or not run both of the below mentioned commands and check if `nvcc -V` give output or not

    ```
    cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version

    nvcc -V
    ```
13. Go to `~/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery`, then run these:

    ```
    make

    ./deviceQuery
    ```

    and match the output with this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fusu.png), your might be different but the  output format should match.
14. **Congrats** you **installed CUDA Toolkit successfully**. After that go here and try some examples [Go to 7.2 Recommended Actions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) .

COURTESY - [CUDA TOOLKIT DOCS](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html)

P.S - Any type of criticism is welcome, apologizes in advance for any mistakes, this is my first answer on askubuntu.com.

**THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR READING:)**

Comment: You could add that first selecting 'enable networking' will remount the as read/write without fuzz., or add the line where you remounted to read/write from command prompt.

Comment: @Videonauth Thanks for the edit. I didn't understand your point, I didn't do any remounting. Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: That is weird because afaik Ubuntu mounts the drive in read only mode when dropping to root shell at the start.

Comment: It's true but in my case root shell disappears after sometime which it do generally and then I again selected it and it worked fine for me. Did you mean  that I should give reference to that chmod  and  mount remount stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Having done this multiple times, successfully/unsuccessfully loosing my display, coming here - gaining insights - some cuda libs not in path, missing , not installed - the sane way is to just install the linux drivers for your nvidia-card https://medium.com/techlogs/install-the-right-nvidia-driver-for-cuda-in-ubuntu-2d9ade437dec
and work on [nvidia-cuda docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/) images - base or devel.

Do volume mapping from your code folder to the container - install what you want - 
Same with working with keras or tensorflow or just pure [opencv](https://medium.com/techlogs/compiling-opencv-for-cuda-for-yolo-and-other-cnn-libraries-9ce427c00ff8)

> docker run --net=host --runtime=nvidia -it -v ~/coding:/coding  nvidia/cuda: /bin/bash

Note TF also comes with its docker

Answer (score 0):

I have tested these steps to install cuda for several LTS including 20.04 and 22.04 ... most answers here are obsolete and should be avoided

Its helpful to run a LTS version of Ubuntu which happens every even numbered year as in 16.04, 18.04, 20.04, 22.0 etc ... because its less of a moving target for driver owners AND the cuda download site specifically only lists LTS versions

First purge any nvidia drivers you may have installed

```
sudo apt purge *nvidia* -y   # this will auto give you nouveau graphics drivers
```

confirm above by listing all related packages

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia # do above purge if need be
```

Delete any files in dir `/var/crash`   or install below will error out

```
reboot
```

Goto cuda download page https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads    Linux -> x86_64 (unless U are on ARM) ->  Ubuntu -> pick matching LTS of your Ubuntu install

then in a terminal issue all commands listed in above site

```
reboot
```

Now confirm you have cuda installed by issuing

```
nvcc --version
```

NOTICE - above will auto install appropriate nvidia graphics drivers to match your Ubuntu LTS release, cuda version and your hardware