# Can't install Cuda 8, but have correct nvidia driver (Ubuntu 16)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I have nvidia driver 367.57 but I keep getting this message when I try to install cuda 8:

> ***WARNING: Incomplete installation! This installation did not install the CUDA Driver. A driver of version at least 361.00 is required for CUDA 8.0 functionality to work.

Even though, I tried to run tensorflow but, as predicted, it can't find cuda:

> ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/799184/how-can-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-16-04  What Nvidia hardware do you have?  Did you look at http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/secure/prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf?autho=1485052169_f0a8e9b287a6f4d8e7c51948d574f684&file=CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf  Did you add the ...cuda-8.0/bin to your path?

Comment: Thank you so much! my problem was adding cuda to path, this did the trick: export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda | export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The necessary modifications for finding executables and libraries are to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and the PATH variable.  Since the modifications are similar in the first part, define that part as CUDA_HOME .

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
```

or where ever you installed it
Then for the libaries:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64
```

and the executables like nvcc:

```
export PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```