# Cuda and cudnn install. Where is cudnn_samples_v7?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I am follow this to install cuda and cudnn http://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html

Does the below output mean that cuda is already properly installed ? What other code must i type to check if cuda has been properly installed ?

```
usr@usr-P15SM:~$ ldconfig -p | grep cuda
libicudata.so.55 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55
libcudart.so.7.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.7.5
libcudart.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so
libcuda.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
libcuda.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
libcuda.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
libcuda.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so

usr@usr-P15SM:~$ nvidia-smi
Wed Apr  4 10:22:41 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.111                Driver Version: 384.111                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 780M    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    173MiB /  4036MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

usr@usr-P15SM:~$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

But when i go to this step http://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html#verify,

> To verify that cuDNN is installed and is running properly, compile the
>   mnistCUDNN sample located in the /usr/src/cudnn_samples_v7 directory
>   in the debian file.

but i cannot find /usr/src/cudnn_samples_v7 ? Help please easy question free points.

Answer (score 4):

You need to download a separate file cuDNN v7.1.3 Code Samples and User Guide for Ubuntu16.04 (Deb) from the same page where you got CuDNN files, and install it with dpkg.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to go to < /usr/src/cudnn_samples_v7> to ensure the installation if you installed the cuDNN with .tgz file.

You can ensure the installation by following:

```
cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2
```

It will show the following O/P

```
CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2
#define CUDNN_MAJOR 7
#define CUDNN_MINOR 6
#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 5
--
#define CUDNN_VERSION (CUDNN_MAJOR * 1000 + CUDNN_MINOR * 100 + CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL)

#include "driver_types.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

[Nvidia SDK doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html#installlinux-deb):

> 2.3.2. Installing from a Debian File
>
> 4. Install the code samples and the cuDNN Library User Guide, for example:
>    `sudo dpkg -i libcudnn7-doc_7.0.3.11-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb`

You need to download the deb file and install the code samples with the above code.