# cannot reinstall cuda 8 correctly (cuda folder does not show up anymore in user/local/) after in unistalled it and removed the cuda folder

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, uninstall, cuda, reinstall

I am a Linux newbie.

I am dealing with cuda 8 and Ubuntu 16.04 for 10 hours and it just does not like to work.
Please HELP!!!

I messed up during my cuda8 installation and had to uninstall and delete cuda.
I used the following commands to uninstall the cuda completely.

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-cuda-toolkit
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove nvidia-cuda-toolkit
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-cuda-toolkit 
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nvidia-cuda-toolkit
rm -rf  /usr/local/cuda*
rm -rf  /usr/local/cuda
```

The problem starts from here:
Now im trying to instal cuda again via:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-rc_8.0.27-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
sudo reboot
```

but  no matter what I do, the cuda folder does not appear in

> /usr/local/

anymore!!!
When I check to see what version I have via

```
nvcc --version
```

it shows cuda 7.5. and for some reason cuda 8 is not even recognized and also the folder cuda do not appears.
Is it because I removed the folders from the root? I have no Idea :(

Any suggestion or help would really be appreciated!!

Comment: I have the same problem right now. Have you solved your problem?

Comment: See my answer in :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/799184/how-can-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-16-04