# Can I install Cuda 5.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, lts

I have an GF FTX 950M on my laptop and the cuda version for this graffic card is cuda 5.0.
I'm using ubuntu 16.04LTS 64bit and the cuda 5.0 is for ubuntu 11.10.

when i run the cuda-5-0.run for 11.1 64bit from nvidia with out install the driver i got the error

```
       Unsupported compiler: 5.4.0
Cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-5.0

===========
= Summary =
===========

Driver:   Not Selected
Toolkit:  Installation Failed. Using unsupported Compiler.
Samples:  Cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-5.0
```

i check for compiler version on http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_0/rel/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes_And_Errata.txt

And i got

```
**  Distributions Currently Supported  

    Distribution       32 64  Kernel                 GCC         GLIBC        
    -----------------  -- --  ---------------------  ----------  -------------
    Fedora 16          X  X   3.1.0-7.fc16           4.6.2       2.14.90      
    ICC Compiler 12.1     X                                                   
    OpenSUSE 12.1         X   3.1.0-1.2-desktop      4.6.2       2.14.1       
    Red Hat RHEL 6.x      X   2.6.32-131.0.15.el6    4.4.5       2.12         
    Red Hat RHEL 5.5+     X   2.6.18-238.el5         4.1.2       2.5          
    SUSE SLES 11 SP2      X   3.0.13-0.27-pae        4.3.4       2.11.3       
    SUSE SLES 11.1     X  X   2.6.32.12-0.7-pae      4.3.4       2.11.1       
    Ubuntu 11.10       X  X   3.0.0-19-generic-pae   4.6.1       2.13         
    Ubuntu 10.04       X  X   2.6.35-23-generic      4.4.5       2.12.1
```

The Gcc is 4.6.1 and Glibc is 2.13 so i go to apt-get and there is no gcc 4.6 it start on 4.7 and go on.

PS:

if i try ./cuda-5-0.run --override it install but don't work, and can't run the samples and nvcc does not exist when i try run it

if i do apt-get install nvidia....cuda.... it install very well but i cant do nothing in cuda with out get errors and does not pass on query sample

thank for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused by the CUDA version and compute capability. The CUDA version is just the version of the software/API installed and the compute capability is the feature level that your GPU supports.

Your GPU has compute capability 5.0 and this doesn't directly relate to the CUDA version, so you don't need to install CUDA 5.0. You should be able to use your GPU wit CUDA >= 7.5 so the latest one from the [website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) or repos should work. If it doesn't please post what you tried and what error you got.

Comment: hummm ok i think i understand, so this is what i do for installing cuda:

sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-*

after i go to additional drivers and ger the nvidia dirver from there.
i donwnload the cuda runfile (.run) from you link 

basically i following this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/799184/how-can-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-16-04 

after i post if work for me
Thanks for help