# Install CUDA to different directory in 16.04

Tags: software-installation, directory, cuda

Is it possible to install CUDA to a directory other than `/usr/local/`? I have very limited space on my drive. I'm using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799184/how-can-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install it currently.

I'm using it for TensorFlow.

Answer (score 3):

### The following worked when installing CUDA 8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Download the (local) `.run` file from the [CUDA downloads page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).

Consulting [NVIDIA's CUDA Installation Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7.5/Prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf) page 34 (PDF page 38):

```
The Runfile installation asks where you wish to install the Toolkit and the 
Samples during an interactive install. If installing using a non-interactive 
install, you can use the --toolkitpath and --samplespath parameters to 
change the install location:
$ ./runfile.run --silent \
  --toolkit --toolkitpath=/my/new/toolkit \
  --samples --samplespath=/my/new/samples
```

Where `/my/new/` is your new CUDA install directory (on a partition with sufficient space). Previously, it was installed to `/usr/local/cuda/` or `/usr/local/cuda-x.x`.

The folders `/my/new/toolkit` and `/my/new/samples` are created automatically.

Also, I found it useful to use the `--tmpdir=/some/path/` flag, which [sets which directory to temporarily store the files](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/786641/cuda-setup-and-installation/slackware-cannot-install-not-enough-space-on-partition-mounted-at-/). Use a directory in a partition with a lot of space.

So finally, the command becomes:

```
$ ./runfile.run --silent --toolkit --toolkitpath=/my/new/toolkit --samples --samplespath=/my/new/samples --tmpdir=/my/new/
```

You can run the above with the `--help` flag or consult the [CUDA Linux docs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) to see all installation possibilities.

After this, it is necessary to redirect the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables. Add the following lines to the bottom of your `.bashrc` file (which is in your home directory):

```
export PATH=/my/new/toolkit/bin/:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/new/toolkit/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You must then run `source /home/username/.bashrc` to run the file and load the environment variables.

Run `nvcc --version` to confirm that CUDA is installed. Get the version with `cat /my/new/toolkit/version.txt`.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/799185/423707) for more help.

### Additional help to install TensorFlow with Anaconda:

This part was specific to my use-case, but to install TensorFlow with Anaconda after installing CUDA, run `conda install -c jjhelmus tensorflow-gpu` (from [here](https://anaconda.org/jjhelmus/tensorflow-gpu). The [Anaconda one](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu) doesn't seem to work).

Comment: Specifying the local directory for --tmpdir saved me from getting Disk space error, which had frustrated me for a while. I had used local directories for other two options and I kept on getting the space error.

Answer (score 2):

Refer the [NVIDIA's CUDA Installation Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7.5/Prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf) page 32/33(_according to PDF reader page 36/37) for more details on how to install at the custom location for the CUDA libaries, and also what environment variables to set to make it work.

**Update:**
As per the documentation:

**Runfile**
The Runfile can be extracted into the standalone Toolkit, Samples and
Driver Runfiles by using the **--extract** parameter. The Toolkit and Samples
standalone Runfiles can be further extracted by running:

```
$ ./runfile.run --tar mxvf
```

The Driver Runfile can be extracted by running:

```
$ ./runfile.run -x
```

...
For debian systems:

```
$ dpkg-deb -x  package.deb output_dir
# Where package.deb is the downloaded debian package for cuda 
# and output_dir is the directory where you want to extract the files.
```

**Update 2:**

As commented by the OP the installation guide page 34 ( PDF Reader Page 38) contains the necessary steps/references posted below for reference here:

```
How do I install the Toolkit in a different location?

The Runfile installation asks where you wish to install the Toolkit and the 
Samples during an interactive install. If installing using a non-interactive 
install, you can use the --toolkitpath and --samplespath parameters to 
change the install location:
$ ./runfile.run --silent \
  --toolkit --toolkitpath=/my/new/toolkit \
  --samples --samplespath=/my/new/samples


The RPM and Deb packages cannot be installed to a custom install location 
directly using the package managers. See the "Install CUDA to a specific 
directory using the Package Manager installation method" scenario in the 
Advanced Setup section for more information.
```

Comment: Do you mind summarizing the instructions (as is standard for AskUbuntu incase the link goes dead).

Comment: Actually a possibly better answer is on page 34 of the same pdf: once you have the runfile, use`$ ./runfile.run --silent \
 --toolkit --toolkitpath=/my/new/toolkit \
 --samples --samplespath=/my/new/samples`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I required a custom location for all like `toolkit`, `samples`, `librray`. So instead of setting all separately I used `--installpath=<path>` which I got to know about by running `./cuda-installer.run --help`

I was installing **cuda 10.2 linux toolkit**