# Boot system on runlevel 3 to install Cuda on Ubuntu 16.04 (Virtual Machine)

Tags: nvidia, cuda

As in Cuda Quick Start Install I'm trying to install Cuda using .run file.
My problem is that I didn't know how to disable server X. To do that, according to what I understood, I need to switch to runlevel 3, but I didn't know how to do it. 
I followed [these steps](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7.5/Prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf) but it didn't work.

Interface I get when trying to switch to runlevel 3:

[image]

How to switch to runlevel 3 ? How to install `cuda` on Ubuntu 16.04LTS?

Note: I'm using a virtual Machine and I couldn't write anything when that interface appeared.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install CUDA on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799184/how-can-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I checked that link. so it's not a duplicate the solution there didn't work for me. I'm using Virtual Machine I forgot to mention it at first.

Comment: What did not work for you ? Also, FYI, I doubt cuda will work in a virtual machine but I am not sure.

Comment: From nvidia - https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/398347/cuda-programming-and-performance/cuda-on-dell-server-with-virtualization/ "CUDA will not work inside of a virtual machine. The GPU must be fully visible to the OS."

Comment: isn't that link too old? 2008 ..I mean things may change.. I wonder if so why didn't I find it in the official documentation

Comment: You would have to ask on the nvidia or virtualbox forums. I dont think virtualbox has direct pass through of the GPU. Other technologies perhaps https://superuser.com/questions/945740/passthrough-graphics-card-to-virtualbox and https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=112013

Comment: Well I think it's possible. Here an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31627982/6837132

Comment: That link does not say it is possible with Virtualbox. Did you check your hardware with any of the links I gave you ? It is possible with Xen and KVM but with a limited set of hardware.

Comment: At any rate, runleves are somewhat obsolete terminology. You stop your display manager, lightdm, gdm, kdm, whatever you are using or boot to recovery mode and remount your root file system rw - `mount -o remount,rw /` and then install cuda. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/799184/how-can-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-16-04 . you will have a command line only interface.