# TTY console not working on Imac/Ubuntu16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, mac, cuda

Ok,

I've installed ubuntu 16.04 on my 2015 Imac (Geforce 700 series).
Installation was a succes on first sight. Anything works.

So I proceed to go further with my project to install some Machine Learning software. Ofcourse I need my Nvidia Geforce 700 series to work for computing everything. So by default it installed the Nvidia x server 'driver'.

Next step was to install the proper nvidia drivers, [cuda](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799184/how-can-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-16-04) & cuddn. But to do that I need to access the tty console. And that just gives me a black screen.
I've already follow three different SE answers with no result. 
This one for the driver = [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run)

Whereas `sudo service lightdm stop` stops my imac from working, until I reboot (bla(n)k screen)

Also tried changing the grub file = [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162535/why-does-switching-to-the-tty-give-me-a-blank-screen)

I've tried it all in this question, no results. Other than when booting into ubuntu it doesn't recognize video mode. But afterwards It shows me a big Nvidia logo.

So how do I get this tty terminal to work on a 2015 Imac/Ubuntu installation (refind)

following to list my tty gives me this:

```
ps aux | grep tty
root      1042  0.8  1.1 496916 187092 tty7    Ssl+ 10:36   0:09 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
root      1429  0.0  0.0  23008  1796 tty1     Ss+  10:36   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
root      3202  0.0  0.0  23008  1784 tty2     Ss+  10:37   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty2 linux
root      3206  0.0  0.0  23008  1816 tty3     Ss+  10:37   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty3 linux
root      3208  0.0  0.0  23008  1800 tty4     Ss+  10:37   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty4 linux
root      3210  0.0  0.0  23008  1836 tty5     Ss+  10:37   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty5 linux
root      3214  0.0  0.0  23008  1888 tty6     Ss+  10:37   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty6 linux
quinten   3904  0.0  0.0  21292  1032 pts/18   S+   10:54   0:00 grep --color=auto tty
```

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

For those that have the same problem, the "workaround" I did was.

1. Reinstall to Ubuntu Zesty
2. Keep the 3.4 Nvidia driver (do not update to the newest.)
3. Keep nomodeset in the grub file

This worked for my with rEFInd on an Imac late 2015.