# How to resolve driver issues with cuda-9.0 installation?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, cuda

I am attempting to install cuda-9.0 with the .run file, following the steps given in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799184/how-can-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-16-04).

I am not interested in the included driver, as it is older than the currently installed one, (384.98) so I did not select it during the install of the package. Here is the output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.98                 Driver Version: 384.98                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 27%   36C    P0    32W / 151W |    312MiB /  8111MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1170      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           171MiB |
|    0      2623      G   cinnamon                                      62MiB |
|    0      2987      G   ...-token=B5CEA9F4B227E114BC1B94ABA87F7BB9    76MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

After running `sudo sh cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run`, I get the following error that I do not know how to fix:

```
***WARNING: Incomplete installation! This installation did not install the CUDA
Driver. A driver of version at least 384.00 is required for CUDA 9.0 functionality
to work.
To install the driver using this installer, run the following command, replacing
<CudaInstaller> with the name of this run file:
    sudo <CudaInstaller>.run -silent -driver
```

What might I need to do to correct the issue? My driver is above the required version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error comes from an incompatible versions of Nvidia and CUDA driver. In my case, I ignored it and it worked fine, but do make sure that you have `PATH` set to `/usr/local/cuda-XX/bin` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set to `/usr/local/cuda-XX/lib64` in `.bashrc` or equivalent file.