# CUDA install fails

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

Attempting to use the answer [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799184/how-can-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-16-04), the installer will simply state:

```
Driver:   Installation Failed
Toolkit:  Installation skipped
Samples:  Installation skipped
```

I am installing it to start `ccminer`, but something is way off. Every guide leads me to install CUDA in the same way, but it fails every time?

I am on Ubuntu 16.04. What can I do differently?

Answer (score 1):

Install your Nvidia drivers from the Software & Updates "Additional Drivers", get them running first. Then install CUDA from the deb file (local) (after hashchecking it). Install the cuda package from the Ubuntu repos, and add the CUDA dirs to the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Copy the samples to a writeable location, and run a few make files. Test the successfully built samples, or add any other necessary packages (like MPI).  The nbody sample shouldn't need any other packages.