# How to mine Ethereum on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Geforce GTX 970

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I've been trying to get into mining for a while now, but I just seem to be running into never ending problems with my hardware. I've been following these instructions for the mining part:

https://www.meebey.net/posts/ethereum_gpu_mining_on_linux_howto/

https://medium.com/@oconnorct1/getting-started-mining-ethereum-on-ubuntu-january-2017-148c53f8793b

And these instructions for the NVIDIA CUDA toolkit part:

[How can I install CUDA on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799184/how-can-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-16-04#799185)

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#axzz4WNL7OgLr

After many tries, I've managed to (successfully) install the CUDA drivers, with the following output on my deviceQuery:

```
 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 970"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          9.1 / 9.1
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    5.2
  Total amount of global memory:                 4037 MBytes (4233101312 bytes)
  (13) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     1664 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1329 MHz (1.33 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             3505 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              256-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 1835008 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Supports Cooperative Kernel Launch:            No
  Supports MultiDevice Co-op Kernel Launch:      No
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 9.1, CUDA Runtime Version = 9.1, NumDevs = 1
Result = PASS
```

Since, the last line says `Result = PASS`, I assumed the installation was a success. This is my `nvidia-smi -a` output

```
==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                       : Thu Jan  4 15:07:41 2018
Driver Version                  : 387.26

Attached GPUs                   : 1
GPU 0000:01:00.0
    Product Name                : GeForce GTX 970
    Display Mode                : Enabled
    Persistence Mode            : Disabled
    Driver Model
        Current                 : N/A
        Pending                 : N/A
    Serial Number               : N/A
    GPU UUID                    : GPU-a3b994a4-62dc-fa4d-1a3e-1cfbb5d46276
    VBIOS Version               : 84.04.2F.00.81
    Inforom Version
        Image Version           : N/A
        OEM Object              : N/A
        ECC Object              : N/A
        Power Management Object : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                 : N/A
        Pending                 : N/A
    PCI
        Bus                     : 0x01
        Device                  : 0x00
        Domain                  : 0x0000
        Device Id               : 0x13C210DE
        Bus Id                  : 0000:01:00.0
        Sub System Id           : 0x366A1458
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max             : 3
                Current         : 3
            Link Width
                Max             : 16x
                Current         : 16x
    Fan Speed                   : 34 %
    Performance State           : P0
    Clocks Throttle Reasons
        Idle                    : Not Active
        User Defined Clocks     : Not Active
        SW Power Cap            : Not Active
        HW Slowdown             : Not Active
        Unknown                 : N/A
    Memory Usage
        Total                   : 4037 MB
        Used                    : 808 MB
        Free                    : 3229 MB
    Compute Mode                : Default
    Utilization
        Gpu                     : 1 %
        Memory                  : 1 %
    Ecc Mode
        Current                 : N/A
        Pending                 : N/A
    ECC Errors
        Volatile
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory   : N/A
                Register File   : N/A
                L1 Cache        : N/A
                L2 Cache        : N/A
                Texture Memory  : N/A
                Total           : N/A
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory   : N/A
                Register File   : N/A
                L1 Cache        : N/A
                L2 Cache        : N/A
                Texture Memory  : N/A
                Total           : N/A
        Aggregate
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory   : N/A
                Register File   : N/A
                L1 Cache        : N/A
                L2 Cache        : N/A
                Texture Memory  : N/A
                Total           : N/A
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory   : N/A
                Register File   : N/A
                L1 Cache        : N/A
                L2 Cache        : N/A
                Texture Memory  : N/A
                Total           : N/A
    Temperature
        Gpu                     : 34 C
    Power Readings
        Power Management        : Supported
        Power Draw              : 58.17 W
        Power Limit             : 250.00 W
        Default Power Limit     : 250.00 W
        Min Power Limit         : 100.00 W
        Max Power Limit         : 280.00 W
    Clocks
        Graphics                : 1177 MHz
        SM                      : 1177 MHz
        Memory                  : 3505 MHz
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                : 1177 MHz
        Memory                  : 3505 MHz
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                : 1519 MHz
        SM                      : 1519 MHz
        Memory                  : 3505 MHz
    Compute Processes           : None
```

Nonetheless, when I run `ethminer -M -G`, I get the following output

```
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)
No GPU device with sufficient memory was found. Can't GPU mine. Remove the -G argument
```

There seem to be quite a few people encountering similar problems, but nowhere did I find a comprehensive solution. I've found so far this guy:

https://github.com/longcw/yolo2-pytorch/issues/15

Who was directed to a solution, I can't fully comprehend:

https://github.com/longcw/yolo2-pytorch/issues/10

Not usually the one to ask, but this has been bugging me for weeks now. 
I'd appreciate any help! Thx in advance and have a good one!