# cuDNN installation on Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: server

I saw other answers but it didn't help much. 
Here is how I did it.

You need to download all three files from Nvidia Developer site.
https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download

[image showing files that you need to download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxWzL.png)

but problem is that you need to `wget` this files. 
Well, you can do it from here:
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/

Use Ctrl+F to search for exact file names which you can get from links from Nvidia Developer site.

That ftp site doesn't have DOC .deb file (last one - libcudnn7-doc_7.1.3.16-1+cuda9.1_amd64.deb). 
You can download it from here:
[http://apt.cs.uchicago.edu/pool/main/
c/cudnn/
libcudnn7-doc_7.1.3.16-1+cuda9.1_amd64.deb](http://apt.cs.uchicago.edu/pool/main/%20c/cudnn/%20libcudnn7-doc_7.1.3.16-1+cuda9.1_amd64.deb)

Thank you University of Chicago :).

After that it's just matter of following installation guide from 
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html:

From directory where you just downloaded those 3 files containing cuDNN
install the runtime libraries, for example:

```
sudo dpkg -i libcudnn7_7.0.3.11-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb
```

Install the developer library, for example:

```
sudo dpkg -i libcudnn7-dev_7.0.3.11-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb
```

Install the code samples and the cuDNN Library User Guide, for example:

```
sudo dpkg -i libcudnn7-doc_7.0.3.11-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb
```

Use your own main, dev and doc files instead of those in examples.

Comment: If you saw other answers, why didn't you add your answer to the corresponding question? Instead you posted this as a question, which does not make much sense unfortunately.

Comment: This is for Ubuntu server, you need to wget files. My rep is 1 - I cannot do anything there.. :)

Comment: I don't mind if you copy it there. That would make more sense, I agree.

Comment: You could copy your text and post it as an answer to a question about installing cudnn. It would help more people this way.

Comment: I wanted to do that. I have reputation 1 - I'm not allowed.

Comment: Answering does only require 1 reputation. Which question you are trying to answer? please post a link

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/767269/how-can-i-install-cudnn-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: ok, it's a protected question. Then you need to gain your 10 points before you can do it :)